# Ошибка Javascript в WebBrowser

Tags: javascript, c#

Здравствуйте!

У меня есть Windows приложение, содержащее элемент webbrowser. Он должен отображать страницы HTML, которые формируются динамически с помощью XML и Javascript. Все работает нормально, пока дело не доходит до отображения мультимедийного контента - swf-файла. Он его отрывает в отдельном окне, там отображается анимация Flash. При нажатии кнопки "закрыть" данного окна с мудьтимедиа, выдается ошибка Javascript:

> "Не удалось задать значение  свойства cpGetValue и cpSetValue".

Я и убрал отображение ошибок Javascript в браузере IE, написал код для отключения ошибок Javascript в WebBrowser. Но ничего не помогает. Подскажите, может быть кто нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Comment: Это не ответ на вопрос, но все же: можно открыть страницу в Хроме и включить отладочную консоль JavaScript (Ctrl+Shift+J). Если при выполнении скриптов на странице происходят ошибки, консоль покажет место их возникновения. Тогда будет проще понять проблему.

Comment: Дело в том, что эти страницы сделаны так, что запускаются только в IE, там все работает без ошибок. Они появляются при использовании WebBrowser

Comment: Обычно в системе живет несколько ком-объектов связанных с IE. Посмотрите версию с которой вы работаете. Возможно она отличается от той, которая используется в обозревателе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "код для отключения ошибок Javascript в WebBrowser."

Как делали реализацию? Просто перехват события onError в Javascript

```
window.onerror = function() { return true; };
```

или установили

```
webBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
```

Попробуйте оба варианта.

Comment: Я реализовал данный подход:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/622281/insert-some-java-script-using-htmldocumentclass/622585

И разместил созданную функцию в событии WebBrowser.Navigated

Comment: А играет роль, то что swf файлы создавались с помощью программы Captivate?

Comment: Нет. Думаю, программа не имеет значения.